# How to write data to a next sheet when a first one is full?

Tags: excel, vba

I am selecting data from a Database using a function. The results can add up to 2 million rows and since Excel has limit to ~14000000 it just cuts data. I need the excess data to move to a new sheet.
I tried adding a sheet with an if condition

```
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Rows.Count > 250 Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    End If
```

It just created an empty sheet. Where do I put this condition?
The function itself does not work, neither in Macros main body.

Comment: This code is meaningless without knowing how the data is getting written to the worksheet.  What is the function that is writing the data?

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the last row that has data, not the absolute last row (which is what count returns)

Try it like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lLastRow > 250 Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
End Sub
```

Keep in mind, if you are adding the data by just copying the entire recordset to the worksheet, nothing is going to work. You would have to write a loop that goes thru each row of the dataset, adding it to the worksheet one by one and detect when you get to the max row, which means all you would really need is a counter.

Another option would be to refine the database query to ensure it doesnt return too many records, and then issue another query to get the next subset of data.

But in fact, if you are inserting that much data, you should probably rethink why you need all that data in Excel in the first place, as you will just encounter more problems in the future as you attempt to process it, plus it will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there is not way for you to take @braX's advises, you may follow next steps:

If

> The results can add up to 2 million rows

First of all you have to put it into a container like an array or collection instead of just pasting to worksheet.

Then to avoid

> ... Excel ... just cuts data.

You have to loop through this container and paste to worksheet one by one.

Third thing - is to revise your limitation of 250 rows per sheet (if I understood correctly), because 2M records divide to 250 rows per sheet will result in around 8k sheets. You may get acquainted with Office limitations [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Fourth step is connected with a loop and with sheet creation

> It just created an empty sheet.

In order to make Excel put data to some sheet you have to tell Excel which sheet to put data to. In your case the code `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add` just tells Excel to create a new sheet, nothing more.

So in the loop you may use something like this:

```
Dim sheetToPaste As Worksheet
Dim row As Long, column As Long

Set sheetToPaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name_of_the_sheet") ' refere to the sheet where you're starting
                                                            ' this is where you tell Excel to work with this sheet
column = 1 'define column to paste
row = 1 ' define starting row

For Each item In itemsCollection    ' this is a dummy code, just to show that you are going through some container
                                    ' and depends on container type you use

    If row = 250 Then 'this is the condition to create new sheet and paste data there, you may use "row=sheetToPaste.Rows.Count" to check whehter you're at the bottom of the sheet
        Set sheetToPaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add 'add new sheet and tell Excel to work with it
        row = 1 ' re-define starting row
    Else
        sheetToPaste.Cells(row, column) = item ' if row value is less then limit - paste item data to this row
        row = row + 1 ' step into next row
    End If
Next
```

This kind of approach will definitely give you more opportunities to filter data that you are pasting to worksheet with other conditions. Just add them between the `For...Next` statements

And regarding this

> Where do I put this condition? The function itself does not work,
>   neither in Macros main body.

No one will answer this question unless you at least show how it works in your file.